# Python Octal Escape String

Tags: python

I'm doing a web application login automation. The web app prefix and suffix few octal escaped character with password , make md5 hash of the password at client side and send to server.

So when I Md5 encrypt the string using Java Script, I get below result.

The webapp uses https://ideone.com/2C1b5 JS lib for client side MD5 conversion. **hexMD5()** belongs to that lib.

[image]

But when I am trying to do the same using python I get different result.

```
import hashlib
def getMd5(string):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(string)
    return m.hexdigest()
prefix = "\051"
suffix  = "\341\303\026\153\155\271\161\166\030\054\324\011\046\035\344\274"

prefix = unicode(prefix,'unicode-escape')
suffix = unicode(suffix,'unicode-escape')
salted = prefix+"HELLO"+suffix
print getMd5(salted.encode('utf8'))
```

**Result**

```
c7862e873e9bc54a93aec58c199cda37
```

Can any one please explain what I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: Have you tried looking at what `myStr` contains?

Comment: If I print it, I get junk, because most of octal escaped chars are non printable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import hashlib
def getMd5(string):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(string)
    return m.hexdigest()
prefix = "\051"
suffix  ="\341\303\026\153\155\271\161\166\030\054\324\011\046\035\344\274"


salted = prefix+"HELLO"+suffix
print getMd5(salted)

37a0c199850b36090b439c3ac152fd70
```

Not using unicode gives the same output as your Javascript.

If I understand your comment correctly:

```
len(r"\051") == 4 # use raw string r
len("\051") == 1
```

Comment: Understood the problem , In above script len(prefix) is 1 since we are defining in that way, But in case since I'm parsing HTML page to extract the prefix and suffix.So len(prefix) in my case returning 4(\,0,5 & 1). Can you please let know how to handle that ?

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted. But how can I convert "raw string" to non escaped normal string(r"\051" -> "\051"). I tried mystr.encode('string-escape'), but its not working .

Answer (score 0):

this question is old but I came across with this problem a few day ago and above answer couldn't solve it,
so I solved it in this way.

**1- first convert all character to octal equal format**

`HELLO` => `\110\105\114\114\117`

by this functions `stringToOctal`

```
def dectoOct(decimal):
    octal = 0
    ctr = 0
    temp = decimal
    while (temp > 0):
        octal += ((temp % 8) * (10 ** ctr))
        temp = int(temp / 8)
        ctr += 1
    return octal

def stringToOctal(string):
    result = ""
    for character in list(string):
        result += "\\"+ str(dectoOct(ord(character)))
    return result
```

then result shuold be something like

`\051\110\105\114\114\117\341\303\026\153\155\271\161\166\030\054\324\011\046\035\344\274`

**2- convert octal numbers to bytes**

final code is some thing like:

```
import hashlib

def dectoOct(decimal):
    octal = 0
    ctr = 0
    temp = decimal
    while (temp > 0):
        octal += ((temp % 8) * (10 ** ctr))
        temp = int(temp / 8)
        ctr += 1
    return octal

def stringToOctal(string):
    result = ""
    for character in list(string):
        result += "\\"+ str(dectoOct(ord(character)))
    return result

prefix = r"\051"
suffix  =r"\341\303\026\153\155\271\161\166\030\054\324\011\046\035\344\274"
word = "HELLO"


octalCharacters = prefix + stringToOctal(word) + suffix

hashed = hashlib.md5(bytes([int(i, 8) for i in octalCharacters.split("\\")[1:]]))

result = hashed.hexdigest()
```

**Result:**

`37a0c199850b36090b439c3ac152fd70`